# Slidify quiz widget within shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, slidify

I want to use the quiz widget within a shiny app or make it work with a shiny app.  The idea is that the slidifyUI will capture the name of a stock and I want to somehow pass this selection to a set of R code that will in turn pass values to the quiz widget.  However, I do not know how to pass a value outside a shiny app or make the quiz widget work within a shiny app.  I want to:

-Select a stock from the slidifyUI
-capture this selected value
-Use selected stock to extract the market beta and industrybeta from a data.frame called BetaData so that I can extract this stock's industry and market beta
-Use the extracted market beta and industry beta in the quiz
- my quiz code works, I just dont know how to capture the selection that I have made in the UI and pass it to the the R code that uses this information

My code is

````
---
title       : R-Squared Risk Management
subtitle    : Products & Services
author      : Arun Soni
job         : Director of Business Development 
logo        : rsqlogo.jpg
widgets     : [bootstrap, quiz, shiny, interactive]
# download: 'io2012.zip'
url         : {lib: ../../libraries}
mode        : selfcontained
hitheme     : tomorrow
assets      : {js: 'test.js'}
--- dt:10

```{r echo = F}
opts_chunk$set(cache = F)
```

## Agenda ##

<style>
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.quiz-option label{
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1em;
}
ul.nav li::before { content: ""; }  
ul.nav li{ font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px;}
</style>

### 1. About ###
### 2. RSQRM Models ###
### 3. Analytics ###
### 4. Optimisation###
### 5. Backtesting###
### 6. Alpha Research###
### 7. Conclusion###

---&radio

## Exposure vs. Weight - Does it matter?


```{r opts.label = 'shiny'}
slidifyUI(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId='betaInput', label='Choose Stock',  choices=c('APPLE','BASF'),selected='APPLE INC',selectize = TRUE)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("sSelected")
  )
)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  sSelected <- reactive({
        switch(input$model,dtBetaMelted[['Name']])
    })
  })
```

Market or Industry?

```{r opts.label='marketIndustryBeta',echo=FALSE}

marketBeta <- BetaData[StockName==sSelected,MarketBetaCol]
industryBeta <- BetaData[StockName==sSelected,IndustryBetaCol]
```

1. _`r if(marketBeta>industryBeta){'Market'}else{'Industry'}`_
2. `r if(marketBeta<industryBeta){'Market'}else{'Industry'}`

*** .hint

Industry beta is `r sprintf(industryBeta,fmt='% 3.2f')` & market beta is `r sprintf(marketBeta,fmt='% 3.2f')`

*** .explanation
````

Comment: This won't work, since the quiz portion is outside the reactive context that Shiny updates. While this is an interesting idea, it would be tough to incorporate the quiz widget into a shiny context, under the current design. I am exploring other ideas and might have something on this later.